# getting the orientation(Roll, Pitch, Yaw) angles of the mobilePhone using Sensor Manager?

Tags: android, rotation, orientation, sensormanager

I'm trying to get the orientation (Roll, Pitch, Yaw) angles of the mobilePhone using Sensor Manager ,and according to what is written in android developers website, the method

> getInclination(float[] I)
>   Computes the geomagnetic inclination angle in radians from the inclination matrix I >returned by getRotationMatrix(float[], float[], float[], float[]).`
>   and 
>   getRotationMatrix(float[] R, float[] I, float[] gravity, float[] geomagnetic)
>
> Computes the inclination matrix I as well as the rotation matrix R transforming a vector >from the device coordinate system to the world's coordinate system which is defined as a >direct orthonormal basis. ` and it returns boolean value.

My question is, How to get the orientation using the methods mentioned?

**Code**

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    float []I = new float[9];
    float []R = new float[9];

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];

        tvX.setText(Float.toString(x));
        tvY.setText(Float.toString(y));
        //tvZ.setText(Float.toString(sm.getInclination(I)));    
    }
}
```

Answer (score -5, accepted):

```
Display disp = (Display)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
int orientation = disp.getOrientation();
```

Use the above two lines to get orientation of mobile phone

Comment: sorry for the lack of clarity from my side, but i want to get the orientation using the sensor manager